# GUI access NFS share for write

Tags: gnome, nfs

I have Gnome 3 on Ubuntu and I have issue with write permissions for nfs.

I mounted storage to `/mnt/data/some_files`.

I want write files to data directory but with GUI I get permission denied, but under same user in terminal, I can write without any issues. Only GUI has this problem.

Comment: update: I installed rocky linux with gnome 40.10. id NFS share whith AD perrmision control, looks like gnome dont scale permisions or have issues whith permisions globaly. Because in terminal I can RWX but in nautilus, thunar etc.. I can only RX.In same user.

Centos 7.9 gui works perfectly RWX on GUI and terminal In same user.